# How do I import this database correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

How do I import this database correctly?

https://github.com/samanz/cakecart

Every time I import then I get this error:

```
Error

SQL query:

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL default NULL ,
`parent_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED default '0',
`order` INT( 3 ) default '0',
`image` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL default NULL ,
`ids` VARCHAR( 225 ) NULL default NULL ,
`url` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL default NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
FOREIGN KEY ( `parent_id` ) REFERENCES categories( `id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY `url` ( `url` )
);

MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table 'db.categories' (errno: 150)
```

Foreign key is error 150, but there's much more tables than this error.

Please try import first then answer.

Comment: This works fine for me with MySQL 5.1. What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis one works:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL default NULL ,
`parent_id` INT( 11 ),
`order` INT( 3 ) default '0',
`image` VARCHAR( 50 ) NULL default NULL ,
`ids` VARCHAR( 225 ) NULL default NULL ,
`url` VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL default NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
FOREIGN KEY ( `parent_id` ) REFERENCES categories( `id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY `url` ( `url` )
);
```

Edit: Actually you only need to remove unsigned to make it work. But I don't really know why you want it to be default 0. It should be default NULL which is the default default.. :)

I believe the type of parent_id must be the same as id.

Comment: after i made your update i received a new error, i added after your edit

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//Removed unsigned and defalt.. `order` INT( 3 ) default '0', `image` VARCHAR(' at line 4

Comment: Oh. Yeah.. The comment.. Wasn't thinking about that.. I'll remove it.. Sry

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that,You are trying to create table `category`.In this table you are using forign key but this forign key included table isnot created yet.

So first create the table contaning `parent_id` .After that try to create the `category` table

Comment: Don't think this is a problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm think it's giving you and error because you're referencing an nonexistent, not yet created, table which is the table your trying to create itself.

why don't you create the table first then add the constraint(foreign key)?

but there's a possible error that you may run into whole doing this in the same table.  what would happen if the newly added record doesn't have a parent assigned to it?  default value is  0.  will this give you an error because there's no record with id=0?

I suggest you normalize this by creating a relationship table for this.

```
CREATE TABLE CategoryGroups //or whatever name you find fits.
(
`Cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Parent_id` int(11),
FOREIGN KEY (`Parent_id`) REFERENCES categories(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`Cat_id`) REFERENCES categories(`id`)
)
```

Best practices would be to normalize all data and remove all many to many relationships between any two tables by creating relationship tables.